# GemFire 8.2.0 ClientCacheFactory addPoolLocator, how to set list of locators on client

Tags: gemfire

I have this code

```
ClientCacheFactory clientCacheFactory = new ClientCacheFactory();
        clientCacheFactory.set("cache-xml-file", "client-cache.xml");
        clientCacheFactory.set("mcast-port", "0");

        List<String> locators = Arrays.asList(peersIp.split(","));
        for (String locator : locators) {
            clientCacheFactory.addPoolLocator(locator, 11001);
        }
```

I am adding a list of locator ips to clientCacheFactory

In the clients logs i see

- [info 2016/02/09 13:14:15.440 UTC  tid=0x1] Running in local mode since mcast-port was 0 and locators was empty.

  [info 2016/02/09 13:14:15.694 UTC  tid=0x1] Pool DEFAULT started with multiuser-authentication=false

  [info 2016/02/09 13:14:15.725 UTC  tid=0x16] Updating membership port.  Port changed from 0 to 49,879.
  *

my client-cache.xml

`<!DOCTYPE client-cache PUBLIC
        "-//GemStone Systems, Inc.//GemFire Declarative Caching 6.6//EN"   "http://www.gemstone.com/dtd/cache6_6.dtd">
    <client-cache>
        <region name="exampleRegion" refid="PROXY"/>
    </client-cache>`

I want to use the ClientCacheFactory, to define a list of locators for the client to connect to.

The method 'addPoolLocator'  looks just what i want but, the logs say no.

Answer (score 0):

The logs are misleading you in this case. It looks like your pool has been created, so you should be good to go. You can verify by connecting `gfsh` to the locator and issuing a `describe region` command.

```
$ cd $GEMFIRE_HOME
$ ./bin/gfsh
gfsh>connect --locator=localhost[10334]
gfsh>describe region --name=/MyRegion
gfsh>list members
gfsh>list clients
```

Please refer to [gfsh documentation](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/tools_modules/gfsh/chapter_overview.html) for more commands, or just type help in gfsh.

The logs actually mean you are not connected as a peer to the GemFire distributed system. The `locators` property refers to the peer-to-peer locators and not the one within the pool. I can see how this is misleading, I will file an issue against Apache Geode.

Comment: Hi, I am not using the gfsh utility.  also I am   addPoolLocator of ClientCacheFactory.  i want to use this instead of adding a locator pool to the client-cache.xml.  I was thinking they are the same thing.   I know my locators are running embed in the server jvm,s and my servers are forming a cluster.  I would like to know how I can start clients using the  ClientCacheFactory and provide a list of locator ips, which the client's can then use to connect to the server.   I am not using the gfsh util, only xml and java api configuration, for minimum setup, installing,  I use just the jars i need

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. What you have coded is working. I just pointed you to gfsh so that you can verify that it is working. You can ignore the log message, it will be fixed soon.

Comment: I cat tell if my clients are connected,  to the cluster. the last line in my locators output is ```server summary: 2 cache servers with 0 client connections/current cache servers : ip-10-0-0-192(22032)<v1>:62289 ip-10-0-0-193(24317)<v0>:1131```  it show no sign of clients connecting.  I am trying addPoolLocator via ClientCacheFactory  and I am trying  pure xml config in client-cache.xml defining a locators pool,  however I see no signe that my clients are connected to the server cluster.   ?  how should i connect clients to a server cluster ? and what logs should i see when the clients connect

Comment: I think your setup is working. Can you try creating a Region on the server and then perform put(k,v) followed by get(k) from the client?